# automate reporting, create a separate report for every instance in a report via the schedule manager

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, reporting-services, reports

is it possible to create a separate report for every instance in a report via the schedule manager in sharepoint? If not what other way is there?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

figured it out myself. Data driven Subscription is the way to go.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer so others can find it useful?

Comment: Okay your create an table in sql with the parameter which I use in my report. From There I started a data driven subscription in SharePoint and selected for parameter the column header of the sql table. As result you get an report created for every entry in the sql table.